# htaccess redirect - directory and subpages to a single page

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I want to mass redirect subdirectories/subpages/pages to a single page.

**from**

```
example.com/definicje 
example.com/definicje/521/ 
example.com/definicje/592/a.html 
etc.
```

**to a single page**

```
example.com/single-page/
```

My rewrite rule actually doesn't redirect anything:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^definicje(.*)$ http://example.com/single-page/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: firstly don't edit the file .htaccess or the modification will be lost on next rewrite flushing. use `add_rewrite_rule` instead (https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

Comment: Thanks for the remark but I still have no idea how to write my rewriterule correctly. Help please.

Comment: have you flush the rewrite rules as written in this page ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to put the rewriterule just after RewriteEngine On.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^definicje(.*)$ http://example.com/single-page/ [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: [Please provide more context to your answer.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) Why will this work in this situation? Provide links if possible.

Comment: Could you edit your answer ( using the `edit` link above ) and provide an example please?

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin to do redirection for all theses kinds of cases. It's simply called redirection. Search the plugin directory. I use it to redirect directories or certain pages. 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: Unneeded to edit that file.